# Drupal - Add class to all submit buttons

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, form-submit

I have several forms in my webpage, and I want to be able to add a class to all my submit buttons (right now I have form-submit as standard). And also, in some forms I have button which uses AHAH in order to show something, but I don't want these to have the new class, only those button who does the final submit on the form.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or you can overwrite `theme_button` which is responsible for the submit buttons. Place this in the `template.php` file and make sure to clear the cache after you make the changes. You can `var_dump` the `$element` and see how you can differentiate between the submit buttons.

```
/**
 * Overwrite theme_button()
 * @file template.php
 * !replace my_theme with the name of your active theme
 */
function my_theme_button($element) {

  // Add some extra conditions to make sure we're only adding
  // the classto the right submit button
  if ($element['#id'] == 'edit-submit') {
    // Now add our custom class
    if (isset($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
      $element['#attributes']['class'] .= ' extra-class';
    }
    else {
      $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'extra-class';
    }
  }

  return theme_button($element);
}
```

Comment: You can avoid isset check using [] syntax. $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'extra-class'; See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 1):

Or use jQuery:

```
jQuery("form .form-submit:last-child").addClass("your-custom-class");
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need other classes, just make the right CSS selection:

```
form .form-submit:last-child { color: red; }
```

this will style only the last submit button on every form on your page.

Comment: last-child is not supported in all browsers, therefore I need to add a class to all submit buttons.

Comment: it's not supported in IE 8 and lower. All other browsers are ok. Even IE 9 and the new IE 10

Comment: Alright, but I tried your method and It didnt work, dont you know how to implement what I first suggested!?

Comment: try using jquery. see the other answer I posted :)